# Unicode and eforms

Tags: unicode, acrotex

This is my code, encoded in UTF-8:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[useui]{eforms}

\begin{document}
    \textField[\ui{value={Übeltäter}}]{Text}{10cm}{1em}
    \comboBox{Combo}{10cm}{1em}{(Ärger)(Übeltäter)(Österreich)}
\end{document}
```

This is what is rendered:

http://flyx.org/files/eforms-unicode.png

When compiling with `xelatex`, I get this warning:

```
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
```

Why does the text field get rendered correctly, but the values of the combo box not? It's the same encoding both times. Selecting a value into the field will not fix the encoding issue.

And bonus question: What the hell are those numbers? I don't get them in the actual document, and I can't figure out where they come from.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm also getting "+2.00748" before my text fields when compiling with xelatex.

Comment: I didn't. I only got that output for this minimal working example; I don't get it in my actual document. I can only guess that some package is missing here that is used in the actual document, or that some configuration I do in my document is missing here. Looking at the document, I see that I use `\usepackage[xetex, useui]{eforms}` there, perhaps that's the solution.

Comment: Hm. Would you mind sharing the preamble of your document with me? I'm also using `\usepackage[xetex, useui]{eforms}`, but to no avail.

Comment: It's on GitHub: https://github.com/flyx/DSA-LaTeX/blob/master/dsa.cls

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to narrow down what causes this issue and report back.

Comment: Oddly enough, it seems to be the wallpaper package. So long as I include that in the preamble, the junk doesn't show up before the text fields.

Comment: Good to know. I really wonder what it does to fix the error…

Comment: I might make some further investigations, but for now I guess it's easy enough to just include the wallpaper package.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have `eforms` but you can certainly get the right result with `hyperref` alone. I can't figure out how to display the choice menu opened up as any attempt to take a screenshot either fails or escapes from the menu. However, all 3 entries display correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \begin{Form}
    \TextField[value={Übeltäter}, width=10cm, height=1.5em]{Text}\par
    \ChoiceMenu[combo, width=10cm, height=1.5em]{Combo}{Ärger,Übeltäter,Österreich}
  \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image: e-less form with hyperref]

Comment: Is it possible to make the hyperref combobox editable so the user can enter arbitrary values? Is there a good manual? The documentation of hyperref is… difficult to read. I primarily use eforms because its documentation is much better.

Comment: @flyx I am not sure if there is alternative documentation. I just got this out of the manual for `hyperref`.